# How do I change max url length on a2hosting?

Tags: hosting, server-side

My current hosting plan is a2hosting and I was wondering if theres a way to change the max url length. I use a mediawiki setup as well. Its seems only on my home network that I get a 414 error. its not an infinite redirect though. Its always 525 characters long. I was hoping I could just increase the max url length to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the max URL length, I would suggest you to refer some great threads as follows. You can also ask your Web Host to increase the max URL length through Web server.

[How to increase the max length of url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797573/how-to-increase-the-max-length-of-url)

[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)